# Stopping Potential for the same wavelength is decreasing as I lower the intensity during my Planck’s constant calculation experiment

Tags: statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

When I conducted the experiment of finding out the Planck’s constant using a photoelectric cell, I tried to verify that the intensity of light doesn’t affect the stopping potential. Doing this I encountered some problems:

1. Stopping potential for a fixed wavelength (say 540nm) was changing with changing the intensity of incident light
2. Stopping potential in case of white light without any filter came out to be less than the stopping potential by using a 450nm (blue) filter. How can this be possible? Because, the pure white light had all the wavelengths and intensities that the blue light filter added light had.